# Is there a function to find a component layout position?

Tags: java, swing, layout, layout-manager

If I have a component inside a panel with a border layout (it could be any other layout), is there a way to get the component's placement in the panel layout?

For example, I add a label to a panel that has a border layout

```
panel.add (label, BorderLayout.NORTH);
```

In this case, what I want to get is the orientation of the Label inside the layout (which would be "North")

Comment: *"Is there a function to find a component layout position?"* Why in 2 parts: 1) Given you're the programmer, why don't you already know where that component was positioned? 2) What does this ability to discover the position of components provide to the user of the software? **More generally:** See [What is the XY problem?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As can be seen from the API docs, specifically for `BorderLayout` there is `getConstraints​`. However, more generally neither `LayoutManger` nor `LayoutManager2` has such a method.

Typically for these sorts of scenarios your code would keep track of the information in a convenient way. Likewise for events, it is much better to keep track than use the likes of `EventObject.getSource`.